# UserControl drawing in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, drawing

I've created a class (MyControl) that inherits from UserControl but I can't find in the documentation the method that is called to draw the control. Is there a Draw() method or something that I'm supposed to implement to provide my own drawing logic ? And where it is located (UIElement ?) ?

Thanks by advance,

Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no draw(). Silverlight is not like using GDI. It is more like Lego :)

All visual controls in Silverlight are made up of other GUI simple elements. e.g.:

- Images
- Borders
- Rectangles
- Polygons
- Lines

You need to author the components in your User Controls XAML file, or add them to the Visual Tree using code.

My personal recommendation for developers using Silverlight is to use Expression Blend. It is not just for designers. It is far more powerful than the simple editor in Dev studio and also allows WYSIWYG authoring of complex animations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means that every time I want to draw something on screen in my Windows Phone app, I have to instanciate an object, set its properties and add it to the visual tree ? Isn't it a very CPU and memory-heavy solution just to draw something ? Coming from an iPhone background, where I usually draw strings and images directly inside the graphic context to preserve smoothness, this makes me worry about optimization alternatives on Windows Phone...and it explains a lot about the current jerkiness of third-party apps on the system.

Comment: @Eric MORAND: A XAML tree is the exact equivalent of instantiating all the elements from code (but slightly faster to create than in code). Yes it is a pain, but if all elements are made from the basic building blocks they can be (and have been) optimised for performance. I don't know what the writeable bitmap support is like on WP7 yet, but that might be an alternative for lower-level access. Cheers